# Controlling order of operations

Tags: excel, vba

How do I add D and E before dividing by C.  Currently the code divides E by C and adds D.

```
 Formula1 = "=D" & StartRow + x & "+E" & StartRow + x & "/C" & StartRow + x
```

Comment: Implement parenthesis to build something like `(D + E)/C`. Maybe `=(D"` and then `")/C"`. Fill in the blanks with your code

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses to control the order of operations. This should work:

```
Formula1 = "=(D" & StartRow + x & "+E" & StartRow + x & ")/C" & StartRow + x
```

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I had tried that.  Perhaps I didn't correctly place the parenthesis.  Thank you.